# Make a variable from .py get displayed in a Kivy Label when pressing a button

Tags: python, kivy

I've been watching some tutorials on Kivy where a functional button prints a string in the console. However I haven't found a simple example where a functional button displays a string somewhere on the GUI (for instance a label) yet. So I tried to make one myself.
Looking for answers here I found some which are far too complex and cover several intertwined issues at the same time, which makes figuring out what would work in a simple example like this daunting, to say the least. Here's what I did so far:

**simple.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class SimpleWidget(BoxLayout):
    result = ObjectProperty(None)

    def button(self, result):
        print(str(result.text))

class SupersimpleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return SimpleWidget()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SupersimpleApp().run()
```

And here's **supersimple.kv**

```
<SimpleWidget>:
    result: result
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        id: box1
        Label:
            text: 'Type something'
        TextInput:
            id: result     
            height: 80            
    Button:
        id: button
        text: 'Press this'
        on_press: root.button(result)
    BoxLayout:
        id: box2
        Label:
            id: your_input
```

What I want to achieve is to show ''result'' in *your_input* Label instead of printing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ids` that you have defined in the `kv`, like this:

```
def button(self, result):
    print(str(result.text))
    self.ids.your_input.text = result.text
```